# Simple HTML Dom: How to remove elements?

Tags: php, dom, simple-html-dom

I would like to use Simple HTML DOM to remove all images in an article so I can easily create a small snippet of text for a news ticker but I haven't figured out how to remove elements with it.

Basically I would do

1. Get content as HTML string
2. Remove all image tags from content
3. Limit content to x words
4. Output.

Any help?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

There is no dedicated methods for removing elements. You just find all the img elements and then do

```
$e->outertext = '';
```

Comment: How would I do the changes while keeping the rest of the HMTL content since $html->find('img') would return just the image elements?

Comment: @kasakka I dont understand. You just `foreach` over the result of `$html->find('img')` and remove the outerText. And then you do `echo $html;` and should get the HTML minus the img elements.

Answer (score 30):

when you only delete the outer text you delete the HTML content itself, but if you perform another find on the same elements it will appear in the result. the reason is that the simple HTML DOM object still has it's internal structure of the element, only without its actual content. what you need to do in order to really delete the element is simply reload the HTML as string to the same variable. this way the object will be recreated without the deleted content, and the simple HTML DOM object will be built without it.

here is an example function:

```
public function removeNode($selector)
{
    foreach ($this->find($selector) as $node)
    {
        $node->outertext = '';
    }

    $this->load($this->save());        
}
```

put this function inside the simple_html_dom class and you're good.

Comment: Good addition to the library. One error though, $html isn't defined in the class, it's normally $html = new simple_html_dom() so it needs to be replaced with $this as in "foreach ($this->find($selector) as $node)". I've submitted an edit.

Comment: This would be extremelly unefficient, reload the entire DOM just to eliminate one element. It shuld be a better, more efficient way.

Answer (score 14):

I think you have some difficulties because you forgot to save(dump the internal DOM tree back into string).

Try this:

```
$html = file_get_html("http://example.com");

foreach($html ->find('img') as $item) {
    $item->outertext = '';
    }

$html->save();

echo $html;
```

Answer (score 5):

I could not figure out where to put the function so I just put the following directly in my code:

```
$html->load($html->save());
```

It basically locks changes made in the for loop back into the html per above.

Comment: that was awesome!

Answer (score 2):

The supposed solutions are quite expensive and practically unusable in a big loop or other kind of repetition.

I prefer to use "soft deletes":

```
foreach($html->find('somecondition'),$item){
    if (somecheck) $item->setAttribute('softDelete', true); //<= set marker to check in further code
    $item->outertext='';


   foreach($foo as $bar){
       if(!baz->getAttribute('softDelete'){
           //do something 
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is working for me:

```
foreach($html->find('element') as $element){
   $element = NULL;
}
```

Comment: don't forget `$html->save();`

Answer (score 0):

Adding new answer since `removeNode` is definitely a better way of removing it:

```
$html->removeNode('img');
```

This method probably was not available when accepted answer was marked. You do not need to loop the html to find each one, this will remove them.

Answer (score 0):

Use **outerhtml** instead of **outertext**

```
<div id='your_div'>the contents of your div</div>

$your_div->outertext = '';
echo $your_div // echoes <div id='your_div'></div>

$your_div->outerhtml= '';
echo $your_div // echoes nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$dom = new Dom();
$dom->loadStr($text);
foreach ($dom->find('element') as $element) {
   $element->delete();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works now:

```
$element->remove();
```

You can see the documentation for the method [here](https://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.io/docs/1.9/api/simple_html_dom_node/remove/).

Answer (score 0):

Below I remove the HEADER and all SCRIPT nodes of the incoming url by using 2 different methods of the FIND() function. Remove the 2nd parameter to return an array of all matching nodes then just loop through the nodes.

```
$clean_html = file_get_html($url);
 
// Find and remove 1st instance of node.   
$node = $clean_html->find('header', 0);
$node->remove();       

// Find and remove all instances of Nde.
$nodes = $clean_html->find('script');
foreach($nodes as $node) {
    $node->remove();       
}
```