# getting element content with simpe-html-dom

Tags: php, html, simple-html-dom

I'm using simpile_html_dom for getting html pages elements.
I have some div elements like this. All i want is to get "Fine Thanks" sentence in each div (that is not inside any sub-element).
How can i do it?

```
<div class="right">
<h2>
<a href="">Hello</a>
</h2>
<br/>
<span>How Are You?</span>
<span>How Are You?</span>
<span>How Are You?</span>
Fine Thanks
</div>
```

Comment: did you tried any code?

Comment: you want to get or want to insert in div ?

Comment: Can you post 2 more div elements? or whether that repeats like the posted div element?

Comment: @Jenson M Jhon: They have the same structure, but different contents

Comment: @ liyakat: i want to read "Fine Thanks" sentence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built in method to read text property in simple_html_dom.php
But this should work;

```
include 'parser.php';

$html = str_get_html('<div class="right">
<h2>
<a href="">Hello</a>
</h2>
<br/>
<span>How Are You?</span>
<span>How Are You?</span>
<span>How Are You?</span>
Fine Thanks
</div>');

function readTextNode($element){
    $local = $element;
    $childs = count($element->childNodes());
    for($i = 0; $i < $childs; $i++)
        $local->childNodes($i)->outertext = '';
    return $local->innertext;
}

echo readTextNode($html->find('div.right',0));
```

Comment: That's just awful, no offence; modifying the tree just to extract something is backward and should not be necessary in a proper library. Sigh.

Answer (score 2):

It *should* be simply `$html->find('div.right > text')`, but that won't work because Simple HTML DOM Parser doesn't seem to support direct descendant queries.

So you'd have to find all `<div>` elements first and search the child nodes for a text node. Unfortunately, the `->childNodes()` method is mapped to `->children()` and thus only returns elements.

A working solution is to call `->find('text')` on each `<div>` element, after which you filter the results based on the parent node.

```
foreach ($doc->find('div.right') as $parent) {
    foreach ($parent->find('text') as $node) {
        if ($node->parent() === $parent && strlen($t = trim($node->plaintext))) {
            echo $t, PHP_EOL;
        }
    }
}
```

Using [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/domdocument), this XPath expression will do the same work without the pain:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadHTML($content);
$xp = new DOMXPath($doc);

foreach ($xp->query('//div/text()') as $node) {
    if (strlen($t = trim($node->textContent))) {
        echo $t, PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably but the OP tells he need to use `simpile_html_dom`. of course XPath has a better solution than we all provided.

Comment: @silentboy Well, that's why my answer has both; I should start an anti-simple_html_dom campaign :)

Comment: Don't blame simple, there really is no way to get at that text node (and probably shouldn't be) in css.

Comment: @pguard did you see the xpath expression I've used? That one works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

I would switch to phpquery for this one. You still need to use DOM but not too painful:

```
require('phpQuery.php');

$html =<<<EOF
<div class="right">
<h2>
<a href="">Hello</a>
</h2>
<br/>
<span>How Are You?</span>
<span>How Are You?</span>
<span>How Are You?</span>
Fine Thanks
</div>
EOF;

$dom = phpQuery::newDocumentHTML($html);

foreach($dom->find("div.right > *:last") as $last_element){
  echo $last_element->nextSibling->nodeValue;
}
```

**Update**
These days I'm recommending [this simple replacement](https://sourceforge.net/projects/advancedhtmldom/) which does let you avoid the dom ugliness:

```
$doc = str_get_html($html);
foreach($doc->find('div.right > text:last') as $el){
  echo $el->text;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public function removeNode($selector)
{
  foreach ($html->find($selector) as $node)
  {
    $node->outertext = '';
  }

 $this->load($this->save());        
}
```

use this function to remove the h2 and span element from the div. Then get the div element data.

Reference URL : [Simple HTML Dom: How to remove elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8227481/simple-html-dom-how-to-remove-elements)