# Input type html tags are not being removed by PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser

Tags: php, html, simple-html-dom

To remove input type html tags with **PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser**, I tried in following way:

```
// Get DOM from URL or file

$html=new simple_html_dom();

// Loads the file from URL

$html->load_file($sourceurl);

// Remove input type text tag

    foreach ($html->find('input[type="text"]') as $e) {

        $e->outertext = '';
    }
```

I am also aware of this link here: [Simple HTML Dom: How to remove elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8227481/simple-html-dom-how-to-remove-elements)

But it's not working. Is there any other way/work around?

EDIT: As asked, here's the full source code:

```
// Gets the url of the website to be parsed

$sourceurl=$_GET('task');

// Get DOM from URL or file

$html=new simple_html_dom();

// Loads the file from URL

$html->load_file($sourceurl);

// Remove input type text tag

    foreach ($html->find('input[type="text"]') as $e) {

        $e->outertext = '';
    }
echo $html;
```

Comment: Posting the real link may help a lot finding what's wrong...

Comment: Also does your find function finds anything ? [print something like the $index to be sure you're in the loop]

Comment: @Enissay I have pasted the real link, stackoverflow formatted it. Please refer to the formatting styles.  Yes, the `find` function is an in-built function, of **Simple HTML DOM Parser**, it finds many things. Does not work for the code stated above though.

Comment: I'm talking about `$sourceurl` what is it ?, and also I know what `find()` is, i'm asking if it finds something or it's returns nothing

Comment: `$sourceurl` is an input url coming from another page. It has data. `$html`, the output, parses the html properly and shows the modified output when `echo`ed. It failed to follow some rules, however. The code mentioned above is one of those few rules.

Comment: Again, I need the source code of the website or it's url so I can test it myself...

Answer (score 0):

Above code should work. Did you try to output the `$html` variable after removing the tags ?

```
echo (string) $html; // Should print the html content without input tags
```

Comment: Yes, I have `echo $html;` in my code, the output parses the textboxes as-it-is, does not remove it.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with simple_html_dom() but if you can use [DOM](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) you can use my class. It is only a snapshot but should give you what you need.

You can also see it here: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/aa54bdbf416ae1726ef7ca675b2324c37626920b

Here is the class myDOMDocument()

```
/**
* myDOMDocument
* 
* This class extend the DOMDocument class with some helpful methods.
* 
* @subpackage DOMDocument
* @version $Revision: 9497 $ $Date: 2007-12-19 17:03:25 +1000 (Tr, 19 Grd 2007) $ $Author: talisin $
* 
*/
class myDOMDocument extends DOMDocument {

    /**
    * Load HTML with mb_convert_encoding before load UTF-8 page
    * to ensure that the output is the same as the input
    *
    * @link http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php#74777
    * @see DOMDocument::loadHTML()
    * 
    * @param string $html
    * @param string $encoding
    * 
    */
    public function loadHTML($html, $encoding = "UTF-8") {
        $html = mb_convert_encoding($html, 'HTML-ENTITIES', $encoding);
        @parent::loadHTML($html); #suppress warnings
    }

    /**
     * Return HTML while stripping the auto-added tags html, body, and doctype.
     * 
     * @see DOMDocument::saveHTML()
     * @since PHP/5.3.6
     * 
     * @param bool $ignoreAutoAddTags (optional) strip the auto-added tags
     * 
     */
    public function saveHTML( $ignoreAutoAddTags = false ) {
        if( $ignoreAutoAddTags ) {
            $content = preg_replace(array("/^\<\!DOCTYPE.*?<html><body>/si","!</body></html>$!si"),"",parent::saveHTML());
            return $content;
        }
        return parent::saveHTML( parent::documentElement );
    }       

    /**
     * Delete a HTML tag by either a matching tag or additional by tag and his attributes
     * 
     * @example $dom->deleteHtmlTag( 'input', array( 'type' => 'text' ) );
     * This will delete all input type="text" 
     * 
     * 
     * @param string $tag_name Name of the HTML tag to delete
     * @param array $attributes Array of attributes where the key = attribute name and value = attribute value
     */
    public function deleteHtmlTag( $tag_name, $attributes = array() ) {

        $remove_tag = array(); # holds the DOMNodes we want to delete

        foreach (parent::getElementsByTagName($tag_name) as $tag) {

            // if method call has attributes
            if (count($attributes) > 0) {

                // for each HTML attribute of the given node
                foreach ($tag->attributes as $tag_attribute) {

                    // for each given attribute
                    foreach( $attributes as $name => $value ) {
                        if ($tag_attribute->name == $name && $tag_attribute->value == $value ) {
                            $remove_tag[] = $tag;
                        }
                    }

                }

            }

            // otherwise delte the whole tag
            else {
                 $remove_tag[] = $tag;
            }
        }

        if ( count( $remove_tag ) > 0 ) {
            foreach ($remove_tag as $tag) {
                $tag->parentNode->removeChild($tag); 
            } 
        }

    }

}

echo $html = '<div id="hello">Hello</div><input type="text" name="Sample1"><div id="world"><input type="submit" name="Sample2"></div>'.PHP_EOL.PHP_EOL;

$dom = new myDOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML( $html );
$dom->deleteHtmlTag( 'input', array( 'type' => 'text' ) );
echo $dom->saveHTML( true );
```