# Simpe_html_dom: How to remove a 'div' tag with a particular 'class' attribute?

Tags: php, html, simple-html-dom

How can remove all the `div` tags with the class attribute equal to `info` in a PHP page, i.e. the `<div class="info">...</div>` tags need to be removed from an HTML string.

I have seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8227481/simple-html-dom-how-to-remove-elements), but I want to remove elements with the `class` equal to `info`.

I will like to use Simple HTML DOM (compared to any other library) because I am already using it in the program.

Comment: have you looked into using javascript for this? and by remove do you want it to not even show up in the inspector? or just not display?

Comment: [From the manual](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm) you should be able to access class="info" like this: `$ret = $html->find('div[class=info]');`. Also, `->find('.info')` for the class only, or `->find('div.info')`

Comment: @iamde_coder I thought about it but I need to avoid JS as much as possible. If it is not getting done this way, I'll end up using JS though. About "remove", it's better if it is there but is not just displayed.

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8227616/2812842) for how to remove the elements

Comment: @scrowler I checked that. I don't know what `$e` is in `$e->outertext='';` is?

Comment: `$e` is the element -- e.g. in a query like this: `foreach ($html->find('div.info') as $e)` or `$e = $html->find('div.info',0)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways to select elements by class. [Check out the manual.](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm)

```
$html->find('div[class=info]');
$html->find('div.info');
$html->find('.info'); // not just divs
```

Then using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8227616/2812842), you can remove the elements by setting outertext to be blank. In a loop it might look like this:

```
foreach($html->find('div.info') as $node) {
    $node->outertext = '';
}
```

*Edit:* [this is a good article](http://www.phpbuilder.com/columns/PHP_HTML_DOM_parser/PHPHTMLDOMParser.cc_09-07-2011.php3) which seems to cover most aspects of manipulation and common pitfalls (including deleting data).

Comment: Thank you very much, especially for the linked article. It clarified my concepts.