# Php simple html dom remove adsense code

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, simple-html-dom

I am using php simple html dom with the code bellow to get some content. My problem is that i don't want to grab google adsense code

html Structure:

```
<div class="post-single-content box mark-links">

Text text text text text

//adsense code here
</div>
```

And i an using the code bellow to get the content:

```
foreach($html->find('div[class=post-single-content box mark-links]') as $table)
{
$arr44[]=  $table->innertext ;
}
```

How can avoid or remove or bypass to grab the google adsense code? I don't need it!

Also tried the code bellow without any luck

```
$arr44d = preg_replace('/<script\b[^>]*>(.*?)<\/script>/is', "", $arr44);
```

Cheers!!

Comment: try setting the `->outertext = ''` as an empty string, might remove those, you'll need to traverse the children though, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8227481/simple-html-dom-how-to-remove-elements

Comment: Actually, your regex works: https://ideone.com/5l8Lik. Please check delimiters, try with `#`, e.g.