# Display first 4 columns of external table

Tags: php, html, css

I am using Windows software to organize a tourpool. This program creates (among other things) HTML pages with rankings of participants. But these HTML pages are quite hideous, so I am building a site around it.

To show the top 10 ranking I need to select the first 10 out of about 1000 participants of the generated HTML file and put it on my own site.

To do this, I used:

```
// get top 10 ranks of p_rank.html
$file_contents = file_get_contents('p_rnk.htm');
$start = strpos($file_contents, '<tr class="header">'); 

// get end  
$i = 11;
while (strpos($file_contents, '<tr><td class="position">'. $i .'</td>', $start) === false){
   $i++;
}

$end = strpos($file_contents, '<td class="position">'. $i .'</td>', $start);

$code = substr($file_contents, $start, $end); 
echo $code;
```

This way I get it to work, only the last 3 columns (previous position, up or down and details) are useless information. So I want these columns deleted or find a way to only select and display the first 4.

How do i manage this?

---

### EDIT

I adjusted my code and at the end I only echo the adjusted table.

```
<?php

$DOM = new DOMDocument;
$DOM->loadHTMLFile("p_rnk.htm");

$table = $DOM->getElementsByTagName('table')->item(0);
$rows = $table->getElementsByTagName('tr');

$cut_rows_after = 10;
$cut_colomns_after = 3;

$row_index = $rows->length-1;

while($row = $rows->item($row_index)) {
    if($row_index+1 > $cut_rows_after)
        $table->removeChild($row);
    else {
        $tds = $row->getElementsByTagName('td');
        $colomn_index = $tds->length-1;
        while($td = $tds->item($colomn_index)) {
            if($colomn_index+1 > $cut_colomns_after)
                $row->removeChild($td);
            $colomn_index--;
        }
    }
    $row_index--;
}

echo $DOM->saveHTML($table);

?>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please specify what software do you use; clarify what top10 means here; provide some code that you have tried so that we can see more clearly what the problem is.

Comment: Thanks YakovL. I adjusted my post. Do you need more information?

Comment: Yes, great, now the question is quite clear.

Comment: YakovL, I've updated my post. Can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: Actually, you're close. You may either first remove all unnecessary data from the table (now, it seems, you remove only some `td`s) and than print it or print it cell-wise (get a `tr` element, get all the `td` elements from it, print those which are needed; remember to add, `<table>`, `<\table>`, `<tr>` and `</tr>` tags in this case).

Comment: Ok, I've added a tested code to my answer, give it a try.

Comment: Thanks @Yakovl !! Almost there.. Been at it for 3,5 hours now, but I can't seem to get it right. Unfortunately, the page doesn't contain a tbody. Therefor I selected all tables and selected table 3 to be edited. 

The removing td part is working like a charm, but it still shows me all 3 tables. I tried to adjust this getting the body tag and remove the table childs 1 en 2, but I can't get it right... 

Can you point me in the right direct one last time? I am so close!
Many thanks! (I adjusted the code above)

Comment: Hi Stephan. If the page doesn't contain `tbody`, use the container which is present. For instance, if `tr` elements are inside a `table` element, use `$DOM->getElementsByTagName('table')` instead. And if you have multiple tables, than you have either iterate them (if you want to change each one), like I iterated `$rows` or just use `$DOM->getElementsByTagName('table')->item($number_of_your_table-1)`.

Comment: @YakovL I am sorry to keep bothering you with this.. :( I did use what you described (see my commented code). Problem is that if I use `$body = $DOM->getElementsByTagName('table')->item(2); $tables = $body->getElementsByTagName('table');` It still show all tables. So I need to delete the first 2 tables. But it won't work if I use this for example `for ($i = 0; $i < 2; $i++){
      $body->removeChild($tables->item($i));
};` (tables->item($i) doesn't seem to work then?

Comment: Hi Stephan, so what's happening if you try the commented code? What error/bad result do you get? `for ($i = 0; $i < 2; $i++){ $body->removeChild($tables->item($i)); };` won't work for sure, but you commented code is smart: you remove `$tables->item(0)` and hence you shouldn't get any mess because of index shifting. By the way don't forget to upvote and accept the answer once we're done :)

Comment: If this is done, I'll accept and upvote anything you want!! ;)  The error I get is this: `Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'DOMException' with message 'Not Found Error' in E:\Xampp\htdocs\test\index.php:186 Stack trace: #0 E:\Xampp\htdocs\test\index.php(186): DOMNode->removeChild(Object(DOMElement)) #1 {main} thrown in E:\Xampp\htdocs\test\index.php on line 186'. I will update it in my post above.

Comment: Ah, ok.. So are `table` elements actually children of `body` or just descendants? Sounds this way. If so, try another way to remove them: for instance, here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8227481/simple-html-dom-how-to-remove-elements they suggest just `$e->outertext = "";` which would be `$tables->item(0)->outertext = "";` in your case.

Comment: That doesn't do anything except make the error dissapear. Still both all 3 tables are still visible. I realise that my 3rd table is in my 2nd table. Is that a problem or should it just manage to pull them apart?

Comment: May be you should show the html (or parts of it) in this case. Obviously, in this case you can't just remove table 1 and table 2 since that will remove table 3 as well.

Comment: Came to the same conclusion :)
I posted the HTML above. I only need the 3rd table.

Comment: GOT IT!  I don't have to delete the other tables. I can just echo the adjusted table with `echo $DOM->saveHTML($table);` Thanks for all your help YakovL.

Comment: Ah, great :) you can also upvote the answer, it just adds some reputation points to me

Comment: Can't. Need to have 15 reputation myself or something before upvotes are shown???

Comment: Ah, I see. Nevermind)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say that the best way to deal with such stuff is to parse the html document (see, for instance, the first anwser [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3627489/php-parse-html-code)) and then manipulate the object that describes DOM. This way, you can easily extract the table itself using various selectors, get your 10 first records in a simpler manner and also will be able to remove unnecessary child (`td`) nodes from each line (using [removeChild](http://php.net/manual/en/domnode.removechild.php)). When you're done with modifying, dump the resulting HTML using [saveHTML](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.savehtml.php).

**Update:**

ok, here's a tested code. I removed the necessity to hardcode the numbers of colomns and rows and separated the desired numbers of colomns and rows into a couple of variables (so that you can adjust them if neede). Give the code a closer look: you'll notice some details which were missing in you code (index is 0..999, not 1..1000, that's why all those `-1`s and `+1`s appear; it's better to decrease the index instead of increasing because in this case you don't have to case about numeration shifts on removing; I've also used `while` instead of `for` not to care about cases of `$rows->item($row_index) == null` separately):

```
<?php
    $DOM = new DOMDocument;
    $DOM->loadHTMLFile("./table.html");

    $table = $DOM->getElementsByTagName('tbody')->item(0);
    $rows = $table->getElementsByTagName('tr');

    $cut_rows_after = 10;
    $cut_colomns_after = 4;

    $row_index = $rows->length-1;
    while($row = $rows->item($row_index)) {
        if($row_index+1 > $cut_rows_after)
            $table->removeChild($row);
        else {
            $tds = $row->getElementsByTagName('td');
            $colomn_index = $tds->length-1;
            while($td = $tds->item($colomn_index)) {
                if($colomn_index+1 > $cut_colomns_after)
                    $row->removeChild($td);
                $colomn_index--;
            }
        }
        $row_index--;
    }

    echo $DOM->saveHTML();
?>
```

**Update 2:**

If the page doesn't contain `tbody`, use the container which is present. For instance, if `tr` elements are inside a `table` element, use `$DOM->getElementsByTagName('table')` instead of `$DOM->getElementsByTagName('tbody')`.