# PHP, Simple HTML DOM - `outertext` returns only the opening tag

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

Using [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual_api.htm).

I am trying to remove certain elements from the dom. Is is [well documented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8227481/simple-html-dom-how-to-remove-elements) in many places that the procedure is to get the element, and then set the `outertext = ""`. Something like...

```
foreach ($html->find($selector) as $node)
{
    $node->outertext = '';
}
```

And then reload the dom afterwards...

```
$html->load($html->save());
```

But when I run this exact operation to remove all `link` elements...

```
$html = file_get_html($url);

foreach ($html->find($nodeName) as $node) {
    $node->outertext = '';
}

$html->load($html->save());
```

The result is that all of the `link` elements only lose the opening tag, but the contend and closing tag remain...

```
<link>http://www.somelink.com</link>

// becomes...

http://www.somelink.com</link>
```

And if I print out the `outertext` (in a test-case), it only returns the opening tag...

```
echo $html->find('link')->outertext;

// returns "<link>"
```

It works fine for self-closing tags (i.e. `<link src="http://www.somelink.com" />`), but that's because there is no content or closing tag to deal with.

I can't find any other cases of people having this issue, so am not sure what's going on.