# Delete first row of html table in php

Tags: php, html-table, simple-html-dom

How can I easily delete the first row of my html table in php, which is an object from simple html dom?

```
<?php
    include("simple_html_dom.php");
    $html=file_get_html("url");
    $string = $html;
    preg_match_all('#\bhttps?://[^,\s()<>]+(?:\([\w\d]+\)|([^,[:punct:]\s]|/))#', $string, $matches);
    $html=file_get_html($matches[0][1]);
    $article=$html->find("article",0);

    foreach($article->find('article-title') as $title)
        echo $title->outertext;
    foreach($article->find('table') as $table) {
        echo $table->outertext;
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove an element from DOM tree, set its `outertext` to empty string, so in the part of code that you're finding `table` inside `article`:

```
// for each table
foreach($article->find('table') as $table) {
    // find first row in table
    $row = $table->find('tr', 0);
    // delete row
    $row->outertext = '';
    echo $table->outertext;
}
```

[Simple HTML Dom: How to remove elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8227481/simple-html-dom-how-to-remove-elements) is a similar question with more detailed answers.