# After removing snippet using PHP Simple HTML DOM, why can't I save back to string?

Tags: php, screen-scraping

I'm trying to parse through a page using PHP's Simple HTML DOM script, but unable to make the removals persist.

Firstly I want to clean up a few unwanted items. I've gone ahead and removed those outertexts by = ''.

However, whenever I run the next find, they show up again.

By visiting [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8227481/simple-html-dom-how-to-remove-elements), I noticed that I should be saving back to the variable.

I tried `$html->save();`, but it throws up an error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method
>   simple_html_dom_node::save() in /var/www/public/...

If I remove this `save()`, then when I run the next foreach, the `div#bar` that I removed still shows up.

Any help would be appreciated!

```
foreach($html->find('div#foo') as $bullets) {

    $bullets->find('div#bar',0)->outertext = '';
    $bullets->save(); //this statement gives a fatal error

    foreach($bullets->find('span.a-list-item') as $bulletpoints) {
        echo "<br>".$bulletpoints."<br>";
    }
```

Comment: Where does the save function come from? It's not in [simple_html_dom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm).

Comment: Looking at simple_html_dom, it seems to be there:
`    // save dom as string
    function save($filepath = '')
    {
    $ret = $this->root->innertext();
    if ($filepath !== '') { file_put_contents($filepath, $ret, LOCK_EX); }
    return $ret;
    }`