# Simple HTML DOM Parser - removing element not working

Tags: php, parsing, dom

I have the following HTML code:

```
<div id="hero_techSpec">
    <div class="hero_techSpecItem">
        blubb
    </div>
</div>
```

Now, I'm trying to remove the inner div-element with "simple HTML DOM parser".

```
$document = HtmlDomParser::str_get_html("...some HTML code as string...");
$techSpec = $document->find("#hero_techSpec", 0);
echo $techSpec;

$techSpec->find(".hero_techSpecItem", 0)->outertext = '';

echo $techSpec;
$document->load($document->save());
echo $document->find("#hero_techSpec", 0); die;
```

In all three "echo"s, the inner div is still present. I tried to follow the related solution: [Simple HTML Dom: How to remove elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8227481/simple-html-dom-how-to-remove-elements/27943507)

However, it seems it is not working in my case. Do you have any ideas / hints how to solve that issue? Thank you!

Comment: Read that referenced question again.  One answer suggests to use `outerhtml` instead of `outertext`, another references `removeNode()`.  Something else to consider is maybe to use PHP's native HTML parsing library.  It looks like it has all the functionality you need.

Comment: thank you very much for your quick response. Neither outertext nor outerhtml is working. The result is exactly the same. Using removeNode() I'm getting the error of an undefined function.

Comment: Are you using the latest version?  That library was last published in 2019, the same year the `removeNode()` answer was given.

Comment: I'm using 1.9.1, which seems to be the latest version. The function "removeNode" is not listed in https://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.io/manual_api.htm

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
$document->load($htmlString);
$techSpec = $document->find(".//div[@class='hero_techSpecItem']")[0];
$techSpec->outertext  = "";
$document->load($document->save());
echo $document;
```

Output should be:

```
<div id="hero_techSpec">      </div>
```